# How I can fix unconfigured table systemlog in cassandra server?

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch, cassandra, janusgraph

I have a janusGraph cluster on Cassandra and elastic search. I use spring(if it is important) and Cassandra driver version 3.6.0. But i cant fill the server with data. There is mistake:

```
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: cassandra.xxx.xxxx.xx/xx.x.xx.xxx:9042 (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.DriverException: Error preparing query, got ERROR INVALID: unconfigured table systemlog))
    at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler.reportNoMoreHosts(RequestHandler.java:265) ~[cassandra-driver-core-3.6.0.jar!/:na]
    at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler.access$1200(RequestHandler.java:62) ~[cassandra-driver-core-3.6.0.jar!/:na]
    at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler$SpeculativeExecution.findNextHostAndQuery(RequestHandler.java:357) ~[cassandra-driver-core-3.6.0.jar!/:na]
    at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler$SpeculativeExecution.retry(RequestHandler.java:539) ~[cassandra-driver-core-3.6.0.jar!/:na]
    at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler$SpeculativeExecution.access$2300(RequestHandler.java:307) ~[cassandra-driver-core-3.6.0.jar!/:na]
    at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler$SpeculativeExecution$2.onSet(RequestHandler.java:863) ~[cassandra-driver-core-3.6.0.jar!/:na]
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$Dispatcher.channelRead0(Connection.java:1233) ~[cassandra-driver-core-3.6.0.jar!/:na]
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$Dispatcher.channelRead0(Connection.java:1151) ~[cassandra-driver-core-3.6.0.jar!/:na]
    at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105) ~[netty-transport-4.1.39.Final.jar!/:4.1.39.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374) ~[netty-transport-4.1.39.Final.jar!/:4.1.39.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360) ~[netty-transport-4.1.39.Final.jar!/:4.1.39.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352) ~[netty-transport-4.1.39.Final.jar!/:4.1.39.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:287) ~[netty-handler-4.1.39.Final.jar!/:4.1.39.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374) ~[netty-transport-4.1.39.Final.jar!/:4.1.39.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360) ~[netty-transport-4.1.39.Final.jar!/:4.1.39.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352) ~[netty-transport-4.1.39.Final.jar!/:4.1.39.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102) ~[netty-codec-4.1.39.Final.jar!/:4.1.39.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374) ~[netty-transport-4.1.39.Final.jar!/:4.1.39.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360) ~[netty-transport-4.1.39.Final.jar!/:4.1.39.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352) ~[netty-transport-4.1.39.Final.jar!/:4.1.39.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:328) ~[netty-codec-4.1.39.Final.jar!/:4.1.39.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:302) ~[netty-codec-4.1.39.Final.jar!/:4.1.39.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374) ~[netty-transport-4.1.39.Final.jar!/:4.1.39.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360) ~[netty-transport-4.1.39.Final.jar!/:4.1.39.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352) ~[netty-transport-4.1.39.Final.jar!/:4.1.39.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelRead(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:93) ~[netty-transport-4.1.39.Final.jar!/:4.1.39.Final]
    at com.datastax.driver.core.InboundTrafficMeter.channelRead(InboundTrafficMeter.java:38) ~[cassandra-driver-core-3.6.0.jar!/:na]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374) ~[netty-transport-4.1.39.Final.jar!/:4.1.39.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360) ~[netty-transport-4.1.39.Final.jar!/:4.1.39.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352) ~[netty-transport-4.1.39.Final.jar!/:4.1.39.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1421) ~[netty-transport-4.1.39.Final.jar!/:4.1.39.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374) ~[netty-transport-4.1.39.Final.jar!/:4.1.39.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360) ~[netty-transport-4.1.39.Final.jar!/:4.1.39.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:930) ~[netty-transport-4.1.39.Final.jar!/:4.1.39.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollStreamChannel$EpollStreamUnsafe.epollInReady(AbstractEpollStreamChannel.java:794) ~[netty-all-4.1.39.Final.jar!/:4.1.39.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.processReady(EpollEventLoop.java:424) ~[netty-all-4.1.39.Final.jar!/:4.1.39.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:326) ~[netty-all-4.1.39.Final.jar!/:4.1.39.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:918) ~[netty-common-4.1.39.Final.jar!/:4.1.39.Final]
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.39.Final.jar!/:4.1.39.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.39.Final.jar!/:4.1.39.Final]
    ... 1 common frames omitted
```

I manually installed keyspace and table in Cassandra. But mistake didn't disappear. How I can fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

The important bit in this error is `NoHostAvailableException`:

```
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: \
  All host(s) tried for query failed ( \
    tried: cassandra.xxx.xxxx.xx/xx.x.xx.xxx:9042 ( \
      com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.DriverException: \
      Error preparing query, got ERROR INVALID: unconfigured table systemlog \
    ) \
  )
```

The driver throws a `NoHostAvailableException` after it has tried every host in the query plan and ran out of hosts to try. This is probably a clue for why you're getting "unconfigured table".

When a query is sent to a node which has not received schema changes, the node returns `unconfigured table <table_name`. The most likely cause of this is that you have a schema disagreement which you need to resolve first.

If nodes are unresponsive when you make schema changes, those nodes will not have received the schema change so they will have a different schema version to the rest of the cluster. The easiest way to solve this is to restart Cassandra on the problematic nodes. Cheers!